# Build a breathalyzer like device but for testing liquid or semi-liquid subtances

Tags: sensor, detection, transducer, detector

As a recovering alcoholic, I know for a scientific fact that alcohol will altogether evaporate from boiling water after sufficient time, and nearly all alcohol from boiling food, which would have a much higher boiling point, but it is harder for the alcohol in a gas state to escape the mixture.

I would like to develop a means of testing for presence of alcohol in cooked food, tea with added alcoholic tincture, and just about anything my less scientifically informed fellow alcoholics are afraid to eat or drink. There are probably several purely chemical means at my disposal, but they are all invasive, and could only be used on a sample of the substance under test.

I would prefer to harness the power of whatever alcohol sensitive transducer (I ignorantly assume) that is used in most breathalyzer machines, and would like some explanation of how these devices work, and how I could apply that technology to a non-gas based but very similar sensor, say a porous rod that one would stir around a while in the substance under test, or be advised if there is any other sensor that I could acquire, or even build, and use.

My electronics knowledge and skills are at tradesman level, and my chemistry is good at high school level, so building the device and understanding explanations is no problem, although building the sensor might prove a greater challenge.

Comment: I wouldn't try to make the detector part.  They can be bought.  [Here is a guide to making a simple breathalyser](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Breathalyzer/). Starting from there, you can see how to build your alcohol detector for foods.  You'll probably need a small fan to suck the vapors from the food and bring them to the detector, since food isn't known to be capable of exhaling into a tube.  The device at the link isn't very sensitive, but getting it to work will teach you things you will need to know when using a more sensitive detector.

Comment: Also, alcohol used in cooking generally does NOT completely evaporate.  That would take a much longer cooking time than is generally used.  An article I read the other day suggests that about half the alcohol put into the food is still there after cooking - depending on food type, cooking time, and other factors

Comment: Thanks for the link, although I am hoping to find a "non-gas" sensor, and also thanks for the suggestion on not all the alcohol evaporating. Although, I don't consider that one article, or even a number of articles, empirical enough to accept as canon. I will do some extensive research on this, looking in particular for peer reviewed scientific papers.

Comment: Would you accept the empirical evidence from my nose? I can smell the alcohol in various cooked foods.

Comment: @JRE All good and well that you, many others can smell the alcohol, but I will not accept your olfactory sense alone as *empirical evidence*. I would accept a double blind study of said smelling of alcohol over a large population with widely diverse olfactory reactions to other tests in a vetting process.

As far as non-empirical, I am happy to accept your nose's evidence, but are you smelling pure alcohol, or the liquor that was used to flavour the food?